# Como criar um array com o mesmo tamanho de outro array sem copia-lo?

Tags: c#, .net, array, string

```
    private void InversaoString(string Texto, int Tamanho)
    {
        char[] arrChar = Texto.ToCharArray();
        char arrChar2;
        int indice = 0;
        for(Tamanho = arrChar.Length-1; Tamanho>=0; Tamanho--)
        {
            arrChar2(indice) = arrChar;
            indice++;
        }
        string Novo = new string(arrChar2);
        txtSaida.Text = Novo;

    }
```

Veja que ali eu copio a string `Texto` para um array. Logo abaixo eu crio um outro array, só que tem um porém, eu quero que `arrChar2` tenha o mesmo tamanho que `arrChar`, eu tentei utilizar o método `Length` porém sem sucesso. Como devo proceder?
(Quero fazer isso porque quero inverter a string Texto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com `Length` funciona normalmente, olha um exemplo:

```
private string InversaoString(string Texto)
{
    char[] arrChar = Texto.ToCharArray();
    char[] arrChar2 = new char[arrChar.Length];

    for (int i = arrChar.Length - 1, i1 = 0; i >= 0; i--, i1++)
        arrChar2[i1] = arrChar[i];

    return new string(arrChar2);
}
```

Para chamar a função faça dessa forma:

```
Console.WriteLine(InversaoString("Teste"));
```

Comment: Obrigado Roberto, funcionou aqui. O exercício é fazer recursivo, agora tenho ideia de como fazer isso recursivo, valeeu.